# How can i download rds-ca-rsa2048-g1 cert for AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

As rds-ca-2019 is expiring i would like to update my default certs to rds-ca-rsa2048-g1 and also add this cert my trusted certs I'm trying to download for a rds-ca-rsa2048-g1 but it still points old certs rds-ca-2019. can anyone share the link to download please?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html#UsingWithRDS.SSL.CertificatesAllRegions

Comment: For your reference, while I've answered this to help you, please note it's offtopic for Stack Overflow. I've voted to close the question.

Answer (score 3):

The [global bundle](https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem) has all of the certs, including the new `rds-ca-rsa2048-g1`.

The `rds-ca-2019` certs...

```bash
keytool -printcert -v -file global-bundle.pem | grep -A2 "RDS Root 2019 CA"
```

```
Owner: CN=Amazon RDS Root 2019 CA, OU=Amazon RDS, O="Amazon Web Services, Inc.", ST=Washington, L=Seattle, C=US
Issuer: CN=Amazon RDS Root 2019 CA, OU=Amazon RDS, O="Amazon Web Services, Inc.", ST=Washington, L=Seattle, C=US
Serial number: c73467369250ae75
Valid from: Thu Aug 22 18:08:50 BST 2019 until: Thu Aug 22 18:08:50 BST 2024
--
Issuer: CN=Amazon RDS Root 2019 CA, OU=Amazon RDS, O="Amazon Web Services, Inc.", ST=Washington, L=Seattle, C=US
Serial number: 5486
Valid from: Wed Sep 04 18:13:04 BST 2019 until: Thu Aug 22 18:08:50 BST 2024
--
...
```

as well as the `rds-ca-rsa2048-g1` CA certs that are due to expire in 2061/2062:

```bash
keytool -printcert -v -file global-bundle.pem | grep -A2 "Root CA RSA2048 G1"
```

```bash
Owner: L=Seattle, CN=Amazon RDS sa-east-1 Root CA RSA2048 G1, ST=WA, OU=Amazon RDS, O="Amazon Web Services, Inc.", C=US
Issuer: L=Seattle, CN=Amazon RDS sa-east-1 Root CA RSA2048 G1, ST=WA, OU=Amazon RDS, O="Amazon Web Services, Inc.", C=US
Serial number: 74e092b80f69b01a5077c108dfaf3fd0
Valid from: Wed May 19 19:06:26 BST 2021 until: Thu May 19 20:06:26 BST 2061
--
Owner: L=Seattle, CN=Amazon RDS me-central-1 Root CA RSA2048 G1, ST=WA, OU=Amazon RDS, O="Amazon Web Services, Inc.", C=US
Issuer: L=Seattle, CN=Amazon RDS me-central-1 Root CA RSA2048 G1, ST=WA, OU=Amazon RDS, O="Amazon Web Services, Inc.", C=US
Serial number: 51f55ba9aa642d8a54a9c2da8e94c95b
Valid from: Sat May 07 00:20:09 BST 2022 until: Sun May 07 01:20:09 BST 2062
--
...
```

Comment: This is correct answer to the question.